# Check for changes in all other columns based on similarities one column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
FirstName     LastName     SSN            Phone          EncounterID
Justin        Kelley      555-55-5555     517-555-1212    123456789
Justin        Kelly       555-55-5555     517-555-1212    123456789
James         Smith       444-44-4444     312-555-3434    99944444
James         Smith       444-44-4444     312-555-3434    99944444
```

I have a table like the one above with millions of EncounterIDs. I need to know the number of times there is a difference (defect) in EACH column. My example output would be:

```
First Name - 2/2
Last Name - 1/2
SSN - 2/2
Phone - 2/2
```

Any help here?

Comment: And what do you consider a "similar" row to be?  Why would you not compare Justin Kelly with James Smith and report 0 matches?  Is this purely on the EncounterID?

Comment: i don't think any of the columns you are trying to check for similarity would change except for Phone?are these the only fields you are trying to compare?

Comment: Yes - they are considered similar only if the EncounterID is similar.  There could even be two different Justin Kelleys but it would not matter for these purposes unless the EncounterID matches.

Comment: The EncounterID signifies it is one similar file. Snapshots were taken of these files at different times.  I want to know exactly what changed between snapshots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data that you basically want is the number of entities that have more than one value in a column.

This is most easily calculated on a column basis:

```
select sum(case when NumFirstNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
       sum(case when NumLastNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentLastNames,
       sum(case when NumSSN <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSSN,
       sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPhone       
from (select EncounterId, count(*) as Num,
             count(distinct FirstName) as NumFirstNames,
             count(distinct LastName) as NumLastNames,
             count(distinct SSN) as NumSSN,
             count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone
      from table t
      group by EncounterId
     ) e;
```

You can format the results however you like.