# Check for changes in all other columns based on similarities one column (cont.)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server-2008

```
select sum(case when NumFirstNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
   sum(case when NumLastNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentLastNames,
   sum(case when NumSSN <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSSN,
   sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPhone       
from (select EncounterId, count(*) as Num,
count(distinct FirstName) as NumFirstNames,
count(distinct LastName) as NumLastNames,
count(distinct SSN) as NumSSN,
count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone
from table t
group by EncounterId) e;
```

I need the query above to group by another column in the table called FacilityCode, as well as show the number of times there are duplicate EncounterIDs and NO defects by column.

Also, is it possible with a similarly-built query to pull the "defect" results in addition to just the counts (ie. the data behind the results of the first query)?

See link for previous question:
[Check for changes in all other columns based on similarities one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31344542/check-for-changes-in-all-other-columns-based-on-similarities-one-column)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just put the column in the subquery and aggregate in the outer query:

```
select FacilityCode,
       sum(case when NumFirstNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentFirstNames,
       sum(case when NumLastNames <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentLastNames,
       sum(case when NumSSN <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentSSN,
       sum(case when NumPhone <> 1 then 1 else 0 end) as DifferentPhone       
from (select EncounterId, FacilityCode, count(*) as Num,
             count(distinct FirstName) as NumFirstNames,
             count(distinct LastName) as NumLastNames,
             count(distinct SSN) as NumSSN,
             count(distinct Phone) as NumPhone
      from table t
      group by EncounterId, FacilityCode
     ) e
group by FacilityCode;
```

I have no idea what you mean by "pull the defect results".  But the subquery (perhaps with a suitable `having` clause) would get the information for each `EncounterId`.

Comment: This is what I needed for the first part - thank you for that.

Comment: What I meant by "pull the defects" is to pull the data that is causing DifferentFirstNames, DifferentLastNames, etc to increase (the data that is different in the table). Essentially instead of grouping your query, pull *